# Verbs of two words

Tags: grammar, verbs

In 你想走的时候就走吧。 it seems 的就 is supposed to be taken as the verb.  At my current knowledge level, I wouldn't know how to match those two together and recognize 时候 as modifying the verb.  How can I learn to match these up?  Is there a collection of rules that I should learn?  Or is it just by doing lots of reading and asking questions about stuff I don't understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

就 here means ”just”. *When you want to go, just go.*

就 is very versatile, and has many uses. but this is the basic meaning.

的 is not related to 就 here, but to 时候. 的时候 means ”when”, ”the time when”, ”the time of (something)”.

Comment: Does that mean http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/breaking-a-sentence-into-grammatical-structures is wrong?

Comment: @JeffGuy No it's not wrong, as 倪阔乐 wrote, 的 and 就 have no relation here. I wrote 时候 in my previous answer, but yes 的时候 is more precise, that marks the time in your sentence.  就 is in the other half of the sentence, and the two characters 的 and 就 are thus unrelated.